slow postgres 10 query - have I done something stupid with my indexes?
I have a database with a large (50M) table of time series observations and locations (900 rows). The following query takes quite some time:
SELECT *
  FROM observations
 WHERE location IN (SELECT coordinates
                      FROM locations
                     WHERE name LIKE 's01b%');

When I EXPLAIN it, it seems like it does the join first
 Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..42292071.94 rows=54808 width=181)
   Join Filter: (observations.location = locations.coordinates)
   ->  Seq Scan on observations  (cost=0.00..2046681.11 rows=54808211 width=181)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..28.39 rows=49 width=41)
         ->  Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..28.15 rows=49 width=41)
               Filter: ((name)::text ~~ 's01b%'::text)

These are my indexes.  Have I done something terribly wrong?
       tablename        |            indexname            |                                               indexdef
------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 device_sensor_profiles | device_sensor_profiles_pk       | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX device_sensor_profiles_pk ON public.device_sensor_profiles USING btree (id)
 devices                | devices_pk                      | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX devices_pk ON public.devices USING btree (id)
 devices                | unique_serial_number            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_serial_number ON public.devices USING btree (serial_number)
 devices_locations      | device_location_pk              | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX device_location_pk ON public.devices_locations USING btree (id)
 devices_sensors        | device_sensor_pk                | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX device_sensor_pk ON public.devices_sensors USING btree (id)
 dois                   | dois_pk                         | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dois_pk ON public.dois USING btree (id)
 imports                | imports_pk                      | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX imports_pk ON public.imports USING btree (id)
 locations              | locations_coordinates           | CREATE INDEX locations_coordinates ON public.locations USING btree (coordinates)
 locations              | locations_name                  | CREATE INDEX locations_name ON public.locations USING btree (name)
 locations              | locations_pk                    | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX locations_pk ON public.locations USING btree (id)
 logs                   | logs_pk                         | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX logs_pk ON public.logs USING btree (id)
 observations           | observations_corrected_utc_time | CREATE INDEX observations_corrected_utc_time ON public.observations USING btree (corrected_utc_time)
 observations           | observations_import_key         | CREATE INDEX observations_import_key ON public.observations USING btree (import_key)
 observations           | observations_location           | CREATE INDEX observations_location ON public.observations USING btree (location)
 observations           | observations_pk                 | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX observations_pk ON public.observations USING btree (id)
 observations           | observations_sensor_id          | CREATE INDEX observations_sensor_id ON public.observations USING btree (sensor_id)
 observations           | observations_unit_of_measure    | CREATE INDEX observations_unit_of_measure ON public.observations USING btree (unit_of_measure)
 sensors                | sensors_pk                      | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sensors_pk ON public.sensors USING btree (id)
 sets                   | sets_pk                         | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sets_pk ON public.sets USING btree (id)
 spatial_ref_sys        | spatial_ref_sys_pkey            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX spatial_ref_sys_pkey ON public.spatial_ref_sys USING btree (srid)
(20 rows)

EDIT 1
I note that if I run the subquery separately and just paste in the results, it runs a lot faster
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT *
FROM observations
WHERE location IN ('0101000020E610000036C82423676C61C07F6ABC7493045040',
                   '0101000020E61000009CA73AE4666C61C091D5AD9E93045040',
                   '0101000020E6100000143FC6DCB55361C06DE7FBA9F1005040');

Bitmap Heap Scan on observations  (cost=5736.00..480682.92 rows=164426 width=181) (actual time=0.226..0.259 rows=33 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (location = ANY ('{0101000020E610000036C82423676C61C07F6ABC7493045040:0101000020E61000009CA73AE4666C61C091D5AD9E93045040:0101000020E6100000143FC6DCB55361C06DE7FBA9F1005040}'::geometry[]))
   Heap Blocks: exact=6
   Buffers: shared hit=19
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on observations_location  (cost=0.00..5694.90 rows=164426 width=0) (actual time=0.202..0.203 rows=78 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (location = ANY ('{0101000020E610000036C82423676C61C07F6ABC7493045040:0101000020E61000009CA73AE4666C61C091D5AD9E93045040:0101000020E6100000143FC6DCB55361C06DE7FBA9F1005040}'::geometry[]))
         Buffers: shared hit=13
 Planning time: 0.511 ms
 Execution time: 0.349 ms


EDIT 2
The results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS for the original query
observations=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
observations-# SELECT *
observations-# FROM observations
observations-# WHERE location IN (SELECT coordinates
observations(#                      FROM locations
observations(#                     WHERE name LIKE 's01b%');
 Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=10000000000.00..10064467727.76 rows=54809 width=181) (actual time=199211.523..1882472.890 rows=676 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (observations.location = locations.coordinates)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3656427778
   Buffers: shared hit=1227770 read=270859
   ->  Seq Scan on observations  (cost=0.00..2046697.50 rows=54808650 width=181) (actual time=0.057..921543.613 rows=53771319 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1227770 read=270841
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..28.79 rows=76 width=41) (actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=68 loops=53771319)
         Buffers: shared read=18
         ->  Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..28.41 rows=76 width=41) (actual time=0.475..0.626 rows=68 loops=1)
               Filter: ((name)::text ~~ 's01b%'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 765
               Buffers: shared read=18
 Planning time: 0.264 ms
 Execution time: 1882473.046 ms


What is the datatype of obersvations.location? A gin index on locations.name would help the second table scan I think, but looks like it's only 50 rows?

Even in the absence of indexes, I would expect at least a hash join (and indeed that is what I get) rather the a nested loop, even on the unsupported version 10.  what happens if you set enable_nestloop=off?

Please add EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS so we can see the runtime.  Some observations - It is doing a sequential scan on the locations table since it believes that is faster than using the index for name like condition. Convert the query to a semi-join yourself with an EXISTs instead of letting the optimizer do it for you. Notice the materialize - it is saving the results of the IN statement. That might need to be written to disk depending on work_mem. EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS can show this. But converting the query yourself to a semi-join might avoid it.

@Cluster observations.locations is geometry (postGIS)

@jjanes if I SET ENABLE_NESTLOOP TO FALSE; then it runs the same plan with the nested loop

@Craig I will update with EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS as soon as it finishes running.  THe subquery (SELECT coordinates                       FROM locations WHERE name LIKE 's01b%';)  runs instantaneously. And if I hard-code the results of the subquery (see edit), it also runs instantaneously. Can you be more specific about how I would convert to a semi-join? I tried the following but it didn't seem to improve the speed: SELECT *
FROM observations o
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM locations l
WHERE l.coordinates = o.location
AND l.name LIKE 's01b%'
);

@Craig : see edit 2 for the EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS result.

What is the version of postgis?

the postgis version is 2.4

I can't figure out how to test under versions that old (they don't install for me), but I would guess the problem has something to do with the old versions.  On newer versions of PostgreSQL with newer postgis, I get a hash join or a merge join, not a nested loop over a seq scan.

You did the semijoin correctly. The time is spent in "Seq Scan on observations". Notice the number of rows. It loops through the locations (actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=68 loops=53771319). Postgres thinks that the table scan to get the, at planning time, unknown number of rows coming from the subquery is faster than the index. If a good portion of the table needs to be read and with the select * it needs to read the table eventually, it is faster to read the table instead of the index and then the table. For a test select location instead of *.

How come WHERE name LIKE 's01b%' turns into Filter: ((name)::text ~~ 'YGS%'::text)?  And what are the settings for random_page_costs?

@FrankHeikens sorry, I changed the text string slightly for that query; i've edited the original post

Perhaps a covering index on locations (name, coordinates) can help.
